# IntelliJ randomly re-assigns Entity's Data Source

Tags: java, jpa, intellij-idea

I have a JPA 2.1 application that connects to two different databases with two different sets of tables. Within IntelliJ, there is a Persistence View you can use to assign each JPA Entity to the appropriate Data Source and this works fine. IntelliJ is able to validate the Entity's Table and Column against the corresponding table in the Data Source.

Every now and then, IntelliJ (version 2018.3) loses my choice and attaches the Entity to the other Data Source. I find this out when I open the class and find the Entity's table and columns don't match. I stumble across the change some indefinite time after the swap has occurred.

My work-around is to manually remove the incorrect assignment and make the correct assignment. IntelliJ's inability to remember this assignment is getting old.

I suspect IntelliJ might be auto-generating files to represent the classes which are annotated @Entity and maybe this is where the problem lies.

I understand I could add the Entity to the persistence.xml using the `<class>` attribute such that the data source assignment is made in this config file, but it only appears to be a problem with IntelliJ. Deployments (maven-based) to the server compile and run as expected.

Is there something I can do with IntelliJ to avoid losing the data source assignments?

Other notes:

- These mappings are not recorded in the `<module>.iml` file. I remain unsuccessful at finding where this is recorded.
- Using the `<class>` attribute in the `persistence.xml` is not considered by IntelliJ for validation.
- Using the `@PersistenceUnit(unitName = "unitName")` annotation on the Entity is not considered by IntelliJ for validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get IntelliJ to remember the association between and Entity and its DataSource is the wrong approach. Instead, IntelliJ needs to be told the association between the *Persistence Unit* and its DataSource.

Both options are available from the Persistence View that is enabled when the JPA facet is enabled, but IntelliJ will list all annotated Entities under both persistence units which can lead you to thinking you need to open each Entity to perform the mapping.

The only action that is required within the Persistence View is to map each Persistence Unit to its DataSource.